# WHERE NOT ... IN in Linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a LINQ selection for a DropDown List by use of the following expression:

```
    protected void PopulateInstitutionsDropDownList(Team currentTeam)
    {
        var institutions = from d in db.Institutions
                           where !(currentTeam.Institutions.Select(x => x.ID).Contains(d.ID))
                           orderby d.InstitutionName
                           select d;

        List<Institution> i = institutions.ToList();

        ViewBag.Institutions = new SelectList(i, "ID", "InstitutionName");
    }
```

However, this results in the Exception: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Refusion.Models.Institution'. Only primitive types or enumerations are supported for this type.

This is why I try to Select just the ID for a new collection, as I know that it cannot compare two objects directly without a Compare object.

Why is this not working?

Comment: are you trying to say select the institutions that the currentTeam is not in?

Comment: This is LINQ, so everything depends on the LINQ provider. Which one are you using? LINQ2SQL? EF DbContext? EF ObjectContext? Something else?

Comment: Yup, Kyle C, exactly what I am trying. And Rich, I am using EF DbContext.

Comment: If you remove the Where , does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your where . Do the following

```
List<int> IDs = currentTeam.Institution.Select(x=>x.ID).ToList()
```

Then your where should look like

```
where !(IDs.Any(x => x==d.ID)
```

Comment: This is basically the implementation I ended up doing (although I returned an array of id's). Several of the other explanations turned out to be good, though.

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this ? Have you considered `Except` ?

```
IEnumerable<Institutions> institutions = db.Institutions.Except(currentTeam.Institutions);
```

Comment: Nice, clean solution. I didn't get around to using this (as it was solved), but I will definitely try this next time.

Answer (score 3):

i think you sintax might be wrong. In the past I used this to block users from displaying:

```
string[] blockedUsers = { "Jair","Jean" };


Users.Where (c => !blockedUsers.Contains (c.Name))
    //"This translates to SQL WHERE NOT ... IN"
```

Hope it helps.

### EDIT 1:

```
public class Institution
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int InstId { get; set; }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Team currentTeam = new Team() { id = 1, InstId = 2, name = "Team 1 in Institute 2" };

    Institution inst1 = new Institution() { id = 1, name = "Inst1" };
    Institution inst2 = new Institution() { id = 2, name = "Inst2" };
    Institution inst3 = new Institution() { id = 3, name = "Inst3" };

    List<Institution> institutions = new List<Institution>();

    institutions.Add(inst1); institutions.Add(inst2); institutions.Add(inst3);

    var allowedInst = institutions.Where(i => !(i.id == currentTeam.InstId));


    foreach (Institution inst in allowedInst)
    {
        //it should show institutes 1 and 3
        Response.Write(inst.id + " - " + inst.name + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: since I had some free time I came up with a test sample with your code so that you can see use it, check my addition on my OP

Comment: I got it working using the accepted answer, but this was very helpful as well. It gave me a clearer picture of the logic involved in Linq.